# Kubeflow on mac m1

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeflow

I'm trying to install Kubeflow on mac m1.

1. I have a single node Kubernetes cluster running from Docker Desktop. The version is V1.25.0. kubectl get nodes returns a single node.
2. I am trying to install Kubeflow with kfctl

kfctl version gives `kfctl v1.2.0-0-gbc038f9`

3. When I execute the command
   `kfctl apply -V -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeflow/manifests/v1.2-branch/kfdef/kfctl_k8s_istio.v1.2.0.yaml`

I'm getting the following error

```
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/application-controller-cluster-role unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/application-controller-cluster-role-binding unchanged
service/application-controller-service unchanged
statefulset.apps/application-controller-stateful-set configured
WARN[0012] Encountered error applying application application:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: Apply.Run : [unable to recognize "/tmp/kout706984614": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1", unable to recognize "/tmp/kout706984614": no matches for kind "Application" in version "app.k8s.io/v1beta1"]  filename="kustomize/kustomize.go:284"
WARN[0012] Will retry in 4 seconds.                      filename="kustomize/kustomize.go:285"
serviceaccount/application-controller-service-account unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/application-controller-cluster-role unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/application-controller-cluster-role-binding unchanged
service/application-controller-service unchanged
statefulset.apps/application-controller-stateful-set configured
WARN[0018] Encountered error applying application application:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: Apply.Run : [unable to recognize "/tmp/kout783197161": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1", unable to recognize "/tmp/kout783197161": no matches for kind "Application" in version "app.k8s.io/v1beta1"]  filename="kustomize/kustomize.go:284"
WARN[0018] Will retry in 6 seconds.                      filename="kustomize/kustomize.go:285"
```

It looks like some version mismatch, any idea what should be the right version combinations between K8s, Kfctl, and YAML files?

Comment: Please hover your mouse over the Kubernetes tag you added and read the tag wiki that is displayed. This question is not programming related, and should be asked at [sf] or [su] instead.

Answer (score 1):

I could not set this up on M1 as 64-bit VM is not supported. As a work around I used MiniKF from Arrkito hosted in the AWS marketplace

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-7shm7yqkubjhg?sr=0-1&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa

This will set up Kubeflow on Single EC2 instances.